# Database design for job board based on neighbouring cities

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I'm trying to implement the relationships for the data represented below.

I have a microjob board, users sees job listings in their city and neighbouring cities

- user 1 lives in city1
- user 2 lives in city2 and that city is neighbour of city3 and city4
- user 3 lives in city3
- user 4 lives in city5

user 1 posts a job that needs to be done in city3

After that;

- user 2 sees this job at job listings as he lives in city2 and that
  city is neighbour of city3 - can offer help
- user 3 sees this job at job listings as he lives in city3 - can offer help
- user 4 can't see this job as he neither lives in city3 nor is his city a    neighbour of it

How can I accomplish this database schema with relationships?

Comment: I did add some CR's (cariage returns) to  your post, but it's still confusing.... can you `edit` this post with more, correct(ed) details?

Comment: The objects in your schema would be users, jobs, and cities.  It sounds like your real question is about querying jobs where the criteria is more complex than `CityID = @CityID`.  If that's the case, I suggest you search along those lines, and post a new question (probably on StackOverflow) if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be one user table. (user_id, username, etc)

There should be one city table. (city_id, city_name, etc)

There should be one ref_user_city table. (ref_id, user_id, city_id, etc)

There should be one Job table. **Job can have only one city where job can be done.** (job_id, city_id)

Users can select multiple cities at the time of profile creation or update. Which will be stored in ref_user_city. **These cities are where the user lives or user can provide job service.**

Now you can easily find which user can do the job in a specific city.

```
Select user_id from ref_user_city where city_id = 1;
```

now users who can do a job for city_id 1 you can get data of those users from user table.

Let's say if you want to get jobs for user_id = 1, user 1 lives in city 1 & can provide job service in city 2,3 & 4.

```
Select job_id from job where city_id in (1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: One thing to think about is that Houston, TX is an hour drive from Houston, TX. So a simple city label might not be precise enough for people looking for jobs. I've seen one system that used a LAT\LONG grid coordinate for each town, and based searches that used the nearby flag as within so many miles of that grid coordinate

Comment: Right @johnHerbert but as per the question, it doesn't look like GeoFancing. Otherwise, we can use Lat/Long but to make it as simple as that I have provided the Answer in which the user will add the city in which he/she can provide job service.

Answer (score 0):

@Kemal

You have to create your database structure in the below way.

1. Create a city table with columns (city_id, city_name)
2. Create a reference city and neighbor table with columns (refer_id, main_city_id, neighbor_city_id)
3. Create a user table with columns (user_id, name, city_id)
4. Create a job table with columns (job_id, title, city_id)

When user2 login and visit job listing page you can get jobs by below query

```
SELECT j.title,j.city_id FROM jobs as j LEFT JOIN ref_city_neighbor as rcn ON rcn.neighbor_city_id = j.city_id WHERE j.city_id = :user2_city_id Or rcn.main_city_id = :user2_city_id
```

By the above query, you will get job posting of user2 lives in the city and also neighbor city jobs where user2 lives in.

Hope my answer helps you.

Thank you.